# Using Geometry Proximity to prevent overlapping

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

After watching Geometry Proximity videos on YouTube, I had a thought. I could instance hexagons over a mesh and they might overlap with each other. I could turn those instances into real objects using the Realize Instances node and use the Geometry Promixity node to keep them from overlapping by pushing their vertices away from each other. Something like the hexagons below I've modeled manually. Could that work with Geometry Proximity?

[image: Hexagons]

Comment: i think you overcomplicate things here. If this is one mesh, you just could randomize the positions of the vertices...couldn't you?

Comment: The hexagons are separate meshes.

Comment: you wrote "I could instance hexagons over a mesh" -> if you would let it be one mesh, it's 100x easier to stop overlapping as i wrote in my first comment than using proximity node or raycast or whatever because stopping overlapping is pretty complicated...just my 2 cents

Comment: @RobertHintz, what's wrong about Chris' proposal? Why do you still want separate meshes for the hexagons?

Comment: @AndréZmuda, nothing, I'm trying to come up with a personal workflow for generating geometry in particular.